# Request permission to PenTest on GoDaddy servers

Tags: penetration-test

I have recently been asked by a customer to perform a pentest against a web application hosted on a GoDaddy server. Because the server is not physically owned by my customer I'm aware that I need to request permission from GoDaddy in order to proceed.

Other services like [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/security/penetration-testing/) and [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pentest-instructions) have online forms to request such authorization -- yet I can't find any information from GoDaddy.

Has anyone ever done this? I can't seem to easily find any information from GoDaddy about who can grant me that permission.

Comment: and you tried the online chat?

Comment: I'm not a GoDaddy customer and therefore have not logged in. I had assumed a provider as large as GoDaddy had some similar process to AWS or Heroku (and others, I might add) without resorting to some online chat system.

Comment: you do not need to log in to access the chat, at leat, I do not have to

Comment: I tried their online chat (not logged in) but it's limited to "Sales and Support" and the agent told me to call their hosting department.

Comment: Then that's your answer, I guess. Although you are wanting permission to pentest, this really isn't a security question. You just need to work with the vendor.

Comment: just do it. https://hackerone.com/godaddy and get paid if you hit any vulns.

Answer (score 2):

After calling technical support, a representative told me (paraphrasing)

> "It depends on the hosting plan. Any shared hosting plan you will not
>   be allowed to test. Period. But if they're on a dedicated hosting plan
>   you can do anything and you don't need to tell us."

I pressed further for some sort of documentation stating that (so I'd have some legal coverage), and I was told that it's "buried" in the [Terms of Service](https://www.godaddy.com/agreements/showdoc.aspx?pageid=UTOS), specifically "somewhere related to the section on hosting" ([this document](https://www.godaddy.com/agreements/ShowDoc.aspx?pageid=hosting_sa)?).

TL;DR GoDaddy doesn't seem to care what you do with their dedicated servers; you're just renting hardware. But they're very clear on the fact they don't want you touching any shared hosting boxes.

Comment: I'm skeptical that's the only way to read those documents and a chat long with tech support seems pretty slim protection.